# roll/rotate a groupby Dataframe including the index

Tags: python, dataframe, group-by, rolling-computation

I want to rotate a Dataframe according to its groups and I need the Index to rotate with the rows as well. I want to do that, to then use a find_peaks function to get the peaks that are on the edges, because for me the data is kind a like a loop. Following is a df example with randome number values, where the df.groupby('Value a') is made.

| idx | ValueA | ValueB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 0.123 |
| 2 | a | 0.253 |
| 3 | a | 0.456 |
| 4 | a | 0.789 |
| 5 | a | 0.147 |
| 6 | b | 0.258 |
| 7 | b | 0.369 |
| 8 | b | 0.321 |
| 9 | b | 0.654 |
| 10 | b | 0.987 |

And this is how it should look like afterwards:

| idx | ValueA | ValueB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | a | 0.789 |
| 5 | a | 0.147 |
| 1 | a | 0.123 |
| 2 | a | 0.253 |
| 3 | a | 0.456 |
| 9 | b | 0.654 |
| 10 | b | 0.987 |
| 6 | b | 0.258 |
| 7 | b | 0.369 |
| 8 | b | 0.321 |

I tried:

```
def roll_frame(df, shift):
    return pd.DataFrame(np.roll(df, shift, axis=0), index=df.index, columns=df.columns)

df_new = df.groupby('Value a').apply(roll_frame, 2)
```

The Value is shifted correctly, but not the Index.
To erase the double Index, I used:

```
df_new.reset_index(level=0, drop=True, inplace=True)
```

which resulted in this:

| idx | ValueA | ValueB |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | a | 0.789 |
| 2 | a | 0.147 |
| 3 | a | 0.123 |
| 4 | a | 0.253 |
| 5 | a | 0.456 |
| 6 | b | 0.654 |
| 7 | b | 0.987 |
| 8 | b | 0.258 |
| 9 | b | 0.369 |
| 10 | b | 0.321 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way I can think of would be to `np.roll()` the index as well:

```py
def roll_frame(df, shift):
    return pd.DataFrame(
        np.roll(df, shift, axis=0), index=np.roll(df.index, shift), columns=df.columns
    )


df_new = df.groupby("ValueA").apply(roll_frame, 2)
print(df_new)
```

Prints:

```
          ValueA ValueB
ValueA                 
a      4       a  0.789
       5       a  0.147
       1       a  0.123
       2       a  0.253
       3       a  0.456
b      9       b  0.654
       10      b  0.987
       6       b  0.258
       7       b  0.369
       8       b  0.321
```